# What does ${img_file%.*} in a shell script mean?

Tags: bash, syntax, formatting, tesseract

I know that `.*` means fetch all files regardless of the extensions (I hope I'm not wrong). However, I can't for the love of my life seem to figure out what does that extra % sign mean!

Here's two code snippets that might help describe the situation a bit more :

```
img_files=${img_files}' '$(ls ${TRAINING_DIR}/*.exp${exposure}.tif)

for img_file in ${img_files}; do
        run_command tesseract ${img_file} ${img_file%.*} \
            ${box_config} ${config} &
```

For those who need even more details, here's the [full script](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/src/training/tesstrain_utils.sh#L404).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `${img_file%.*}` will remove the rightmost dot and any character after it in the variable `img_file`. From `man bash`:

```
${parameter%word}
${parameter%%word}
       Remove matching suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce
       a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches
       a  trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the
       result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter  with
       the  shortest  matching  pattern
```

Example:

```
>var="word1 word2"
>echo ${var%word2}
word1
>echo ${var%word1}
word1 word2
```

Comment: Just to add, it will remove any character after first `.` appears including `.`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I will add this to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Just one more small query though - `${img_files}' '$(ls ${TRAINING_DIR}/*.exp${exposure}.tif)` - if I'm not wrong, this generates an array of all the `img_files` with `.tif` extension in the directory `${TRAINING_DIR}`, right? (I'd rather not open up another entire thread just for this)

Comment: Assuming that ${img_files} has previously been declared as an array, then you are right.The result of the expression `img_files = ${img_files}' '$(ls ${TRAINING_DIR}/*.exp${exposure}.tif)` will be an array of  `.tif` files

Answer (score 0):

% here means removal from right edge. For example

consider a variable img_file="racecar"

`${img_file%c*}` will return `race`.

`${img_file%%c*}` = `ra`